# Pandas Dictionary: How to return a key by matching an input value to multiple values assinged to a single key

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dicticionary where each key has multiple values.I'm trying to obtain the key from a dictionary by matching an input value to the values for a certain key

```
areas={     '1':['a', 'b'],
            '2':['c', 'd', 'e'],
            '3':['f' 'g', 'h', 'i','j', 'k' ],
            '4': ['l', 'm','n'],
            '5': ['o' , 'o', 'q', 'r' 's' 't']
           }
```

So far, i've tried this, but in both cases I get an empty value (result is []), instead of '2'.

```
input_area='c'
x=[key for key in areas_dict if input_area in areas_dict.values()]
x

input_area='c'
x=[k for k, v in areas_dict.items() if input_area==v]
x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost done it. Since you need to look inside each key's values, you must access `areas[key]` for each `key` inside the list comprehension. Using `areas_dict.values()` doesn't work because it returns all the values from that dictionary at once.

It must be something like:

```
input_area = 'c'
x = [key for key in areas if input_area in areas[key]]

print(x)
```

The output is as follows:

```
['2']
```